# Groupby aggregation in pandas and sort the created list based on popularity

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have data frame as shown below. which is the table which explains the modules watched by users on each courses.

```
user_id     course_id       module_id
1           A               1
1           A               2
1           A               3
1           A               4
1           A               5
1           A               6
1           B               5
1           B               8
2           A               8
2           B               5
2           C               6
3           A               2
3           A               3
3           A               9
3           C               10
4           A               3
5           B               5
6           A               3
7           B               5
```

From the above I would like prepare below table

```
course_id          modules             #users        Popular_modules
A                 [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9]    5             [3,2]
B                 [5,8]                4             [5]
C                 [6,10]               2             []
```

where

modules = list of modules in that course.

## users = number of users watched that course.

Popular_modules = list of modules in that course which are watched by more than one user and order the list based on number of watches on that module (highest watch at first)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `named aggregation` with [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html), [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) and custom function:

```
def f(x):
    s = x.value_counts()
    return s.index[s.gt(1)].tolist()


df1 = df.groupby("course_id").agg(modules =('module_id','unique'),
                                  users=("user_id","nunique"), 
                                  Popular_modules= ('module_id', f)).reset_index()
print(df1)
  course_id                   modules  users Popular_modules
0         A  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]      5          [3, 2]
1         B                    [5, 8]      4             [5]
2         C                   [6, 10]      2              []
```

Comment: Didn't know you can assign the name beforehand. Nice answer as always ;)

Comment: @jezrael is the Popular_modules list is sorted based on number watches?

Comment: @ALI - Do you use first or second solution?

Comment: @ALI - I think it should working like need, because `value_counts` sorting by counts.

Comment: @ALI - So it means it sorting by counts which cannot seen, so order in list can be different with real data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209755/discussion-between-ali-and-jezrael).